# How do I access this property from 'code-behind'?

Tags: c#, wpf, properties

```
    <ListBox Margin="1,42,0,0" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Metro"
                Name="lbSource" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxItemTemplate}"
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource DisallowDrag}"
             telerik:DragDropManager.AllowDrag="True".....
```

The property telerik:DragDropManager.AllowDrag - how do I toggle this from C#?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using following statement to set this property value to false.

```
lbSource.SetValue(DragDropManager.AllowDrag, false);
```